# MVC: Dynamically create new element from template

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, design-patterns, razor

I have an MVC app. Some elements are rather complex, so I created a template for them. 
I use them calling `@Html.EditorFor()`. The problem is that I need a possibility to create such elements dynamically, I mean after clicking on a button 'Create New' I want to generate an empty template and let user to fill it. I can use mustache template engine or smth like this, but in this case I need to duplicate my html - in razor template and in html. I don't want to repeat myself, what is the best way to achieve this?

Another problem is that when I generate view for IEnumerable<> - razor created proper names for elements with proper indexes. In a case I want to create new element - how should I set these indexes to let binder properly work on POST? Is there is a better solution than using jQuery for this?

Thanx in advance.

**UPDATE:**

Here is an editor template:

```
@model FakeViewModel
<li>
    <div>
        <h3><span>@Model.Title</span><span class="icon-remove"></span><span class="icon-move"></span></h3>
        <div>
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)
            @Html.HiddenFor(mp => mp.Category)
            <div>
                <span class="font-small">Title</span>
            </div>
            <div>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Title, new { @maxlength = FakeViewModel.MaxTitleLength, @class = "title-textbox" })</div>
            <div>
                @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Description, new { @placeholder = "short description", @data_max_length = "90" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

This is how I render it, "Special" is a type of `IEnumerable<FakeViewModel>`

```
<ul class="container" id="special">
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Special)
</ul>
```

So, after rendering this I have got a layout with correct names, I mean `Special[0].Id`, `Speacial[0].Category`, etc.

Now, I want to create an empty template. For now I am using mustache template, it should have the same layout as editor template:

```
<script type="text/template">
    <input name="Special[{{itemIndex}}].Category"
</script>
```

The problem is, that I use the same layout in two different places - in mustache template as well as in razor editor template. 
If I need to change this layout - I need to change it in two places. I want to avoid this.
Another problem is that I need hardcode names ("Speacial" in this example) and manually put index, category and etc.

Comment: Provide some code :) so we can help you

Comment: Have you tried using ajax calls to return partial views?

Comment: @Mike Hometchko, I am not sure this will help since  I need proper names for elements

Answer (score 0):

Whatever solution you use, JavaScript will be required. jQuery is just a JavaScript framework, so you could switch it out with something else, if you preferred, but you should stick with *some sort* or JavaScript framework, as the code for doing XMLHttpRequest cross-browser is tedious and prone to error.

As for your HTML, you can choose to either include it as a template on page load or request it fresh via an AJAX request. Personally, I'd go with a template because AJAX doesn't really buy you anything in this scenario, and it's just an extra request.

Either way, you're unfortunately *not* going to be able to use the Razor HtmlHelper methods, at least without mangling the HTML afterwards via JavaScript anyways; they simply won't generate the proper naming convention required for binding list objects outside of a for loop. The model-binding convention is easy to replicate manually, though, it's just:

```
YourCollection[N].FieldName
```

So if you had a list of `Cars` on your model and you wanted a field to edit the `Color` of the 3rd car, you would use:

```
Cars[2].Color
```

Any good JavaScript templating solution should be able to automatically insert the `N` value based on the object's position in the list of other objects.

Answer (score 0):

Partialview is the solution:
you can create a partial view and have it added every time you want it to be used or injected into the view. you can run a for or foreach look on that partial view and have it repeat as many times as you want.

1: create a partialview.
2: put everything you want to be rendered 2 times in the partial view.
3: replace the view code with partial view. like:

```
@html.Partial("~/views/partials/_samplename.cshtml")
```

you can repeat this partial view anywhere in the project and by changing anything in the partialview it would change everywhere.

Comment: I mean, that in this case I use template like <script type="text/template"> and can't use razor in this template, but I'd like to re-use my template and not to repeat the same layout in two places - in razor template (or partial) and in script

Comment: if you share your code snippet, I would be able to edit it for you.

Comment: see my update. partialview is definitely the solution

Comment: I cant use partials from JS. Please, re-read my question once again.

Comment: but why do you have to use JS? why dont you use MVC built-in features?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a string builder to dynamically create the html in the get method of your controller and then post that to the view. The other way is to create your own htmlhelper.

Comment: Building html in controller is not a good idea. As for html helper - how can I use it from JS? This is not a solution. I want to re-use my razor template, not to repeat it in two places